# Search for sentence that may containing in different paragraph in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, string-matching

Actually here I'm logging an error to a database table (`@error`) directly from the stored procedure. My requirement is I need to log only a few errors, for example only errors while fetching price value. For that whatever error I'm getting is stored in `@Error` variable and I need to check whether this error paragraph contains some sentences like "error while fetching price value" ..

Is there any idea or logic in SQL Server so that I can check if `@error` contains certain phrases in the error desc paragraph?

For example: procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].a
    @b bigint,
    @c smallint,
    @d smallint,
    @e varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @b varchar(4000),
                @Logger varchar(500),
                @b varchar(50),
                @d varchar(50) = NULL,
                @Mileage int = NULL,

        SELECT @b = x
        FROM tabl a (a,b,c)
        EXEC nmc x,y,z,m
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @Error = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @Logger = ERROR_PROCEDURE()

        EXEC [PRC_Save_DB_Exceptions] NULL, 'ERROR', @Logger, @UserName, 'Error while price and key', @Error
   END CATCH
END
```

Same functionality I have done in C# catch block just have a look:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@".*or data does not exist.*");
    var text = "" + ex;

    bool exist = false;
    var texts = text.Split('.');

    foreach (var t in texts)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(t))
        {
            exist = true;
        }
    }

    if (!exist)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ConfigSettings.GetErrorMessage(006), ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have obfuscated your query so much it is no longer valid at all. You have declared @b at least three different times in here and @d twice. As posted your code will never compile.

Comment: For the question at hand you can simply query your variable with like.

Comment: actually i have working SP but while posting i changed variables (for not showing my original data) don't bother about that .can you have any idea

Comment: is there anybody have the logic for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is really quite simple. You can use LIKE to check if a given value exists within another string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

```
if @YourVariable like 'error while fetching price value%'
    EXEC [PRC_Save_DB_Exceptions] NULL, 'ERROR', @Logger, @UserName, 'Error while price and key', @Error
```

You could have done this a bit easier in your dotnet code also using String.IndexOf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx